# VBA receive input and color cells containing it

Tags: excel, vba

I want a VBA script that receives comma separated input (such as "100, 104, 50"), looks for cells containing numbers in that input, and fills their background yellow. Currently it is not working, and the immediate window is not printing as I intended it too. Any idea of what is going wrong? (new to VBA)

```
Function receive_input() As String

Dim new_stickers As Variant

new_stickers = InputBox("", "", "")

End Function

Public Sub color_input(sticker_input As String)

Dim stickers_list
Dim cell_to_color As Range

stickers_list = Split(sticker_input, ", ")

For Each s In stickers_list:
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:K"):
        Set cell_to_color = .Find(what:=CInt(s))
        cell_to_color.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Debug.Print cell_to_color
        MsgBox (cell_to_color)
    End With
    
    Next s

End Sub

Public Sub receive_and_color()

Dim new_stickers As String
new_stickers = receive_input()
color_input (new_stickers)

End Sub
```

Comment: `receive_input` returns a blank string since you never assign anything as its return value.

Comment: True, had to name "new_stickers" as "receive_input" (var name = func name) to make it return it. Thanks

Comment: The colon at the end of the For loop statement and the With statement are also hazardous to VBA syntax. The compiler might fix the errors for you but you should avoid using colon at the end of statements. Colon in VBA  is to join two statements into the same line. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#putting-multiple-statements-on-one-line).